# GetConnection object not returning connection object

Tags: java

i am getting an exception on line

```
ds=(DataSource) jndiCntx.lookup("java:/MySqlDS");
return ds.getConnection();
```

It will not returning  connection object .

and my xml file also contain `<jndi-name>MySqlDS</jndi-name>`

but still i get an error as

> "org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource".

Now what was the problem and what is the solution?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Where did you place the JAR files ?

Comment: @ The New Idiot  you ar talking about which jar.I placed all jars in buildpath library.

Comment: i wanted to know where exactly in server , did you place the jars.

Comment: Your code returns an object, the problem is that you can't cast that object into a DataSource

Comment: @The New Idiot please tell me as per your experience where should i check and I placed all jars

Answer (score 0):

According to [The doc for WrapperDataSource](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/3.2.7/connector/org/jboss/resource/adapter/jdbc/WrapperDataSource.html) it doesn't implement `DataSource`. If you want to get a connection change your code this way:

```
import org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource;

...

WrapperDataSource ds=(WrapperDataSource)jndiCntx.lookup("java:/MySqlDS");
return ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: It is giving an exception as   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource